# RadGrid Filter and RadDataPicker images are not displaying on Live Server asp.net

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using Rad Grid and Rad Date Picker.Everything is working fine on development server.but when i hosted it on live server, Rad Grid filter image and rad date picker image is not displaying...

thank you very much[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you may be missing an entry in your live web.config's `<httpHandlers>` section such as:

`<add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*"/>`

and also from the `<system.webServer><handlers>` like:

`<add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false"/>`

Comment: @Widor: thanks for your reply. but on local server, <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*"/> this tag is not there but images are displayed . what could be the problem.

Comment: @Mohan: Yes, I've found it probably works on the local server because that's where Telerik tools are installed, but needs to be explicit on the remote server because it only has the .DLLs from the BIN folder to work with. I could be way out, though. Do you have FireBug installed? Or similar Developer tools in other browsers - inspect the element that the image is missing from and see what the path to the image is. I expect it's something like `WebResource.axd?...` in which case I'm pretty sure it's the web.config. Also, make sure JS is enabled.

Comment: @Mohan: Did you try inspecting the element in FireBug or similar? I'm pretty sure that will show you the reference to the missing image, which would be a good starting point.

Comment: @Widor: I have attached Firebug screen shots.

Comment: @Mohan OK, thanks - 4th from bottom is the reference to WebResource.axd. If you mouseover that row, does it show you an image preview?  I notice that all the responses are 304s, i.e. it's not downloading a new copy because the server is saying there's nothing changed since last time. The way I expected to check this was to Inspect the HTML of a Telerik control via FireBug and look at the CSS markup to identify the missing image.

Comment: I could be barking up the wrong tree entirely of course. Do you have a link to the page that isn't working so I can try debugging it myself? Not easy doing it through SO comments!

Answer (score 0):

hey guys just FYI I had the same problem and I checked the entries in my web.config that you said to add and mine were already there, however in my handler entry I had this

```
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource"/>
```

I removed the preCondition attribute and suddenly my server deployment started working. Hope it helps someone!